# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, coldfusion

I am using jQuery ajax to call a coldfusion query that I have verified is working and submitting to the sql database. I am receiving this JSON error though: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data`

Everything is still posting to the database correctly but the error is causing it to not go the successful route where the window reloads. Does anyone notice what I may be doing wrong here?

JS

```
$('#employeeLoggedOut').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert($(this).serialize());
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "proxy/Completed.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
             data: $('#employeeLoggedOut').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.reload();
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

CF

```
<cfset session.dealerwork.completedname = form.CompletedName >
    <cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.dealerwork.completedname)#</Cfoutput>

<cfset session.dealerwork.idtocomplete = form.selectedRow >
    <cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.dealerwork.idtocomplete)#</Cfoutput>

    <cfquery name="completeBatch">
        UPDATE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work 
        SET Date_Complete = getDate(),
            Closed_by = <cfqueryparam value="#session.dealerwork.completedname#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="#session.dealerwork.idtocomplete#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    </cfquery>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only send one json output and you are sending several.

Try sending:

```
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.dealerwork)#</cfoutput>
```

Then in response you should have 2 object properties `completedname` and `idtocomplete`.

Seems like you should be confirming the update query however first before sending a positive response